# Restricting cell content radio button style

Tags: excel, validation, excel-2010

I have 4 cells that all have the ability to input a numerical figure (Shown Below) but what i want to know is how can i restrict it so that only 1 of the four cells can be greater than "0". For example if 1 of the for cells is > 0 then then the remaining 3 have to be 0. I could alternatively create them as "Yes/No" validations but again i am not sure how i will remove the "Yes" option if another cell already states "Yes"

```
Standard (24 months) per AP   |  0  |
Advanced (24 months) per AP   |  1  |
Complete (24 months) per AP   |  0  |
Complete + (24 months) per AP |  0  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro¹.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B5")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B5")).Count = 1 Then
            If Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B5")).Cells(1).Value >= 1 Then
                Range("B2:B5") = 0
                Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B5")).Cells(1) = 1
            Else
                Range("B2:B5") = 0
            End If
        Else
            Range("B2:B5") = 0
        End If
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image: ones_zeroes_radio_buttons]

---

¹ <sub>This belongs in the worksheet's code sheet. Right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose **View Code**. When the VBE opens, paste the above into the code pane titled something like Book1 - Sheet1 (Code). Make any adjustments then tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to the worksheet.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this on Excel at the moment but this works using the data validation on Google Sheets as a custom formula:

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$4,"<>"&0)<=1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It didn't work exactly but did shed some insight on the direction i should be heading. I used **=IF(SUM(F33:F35)>0,0,SUM(F10:F11))** and it seems to be working fine. @Jordan Biddlecombe